# How can I avoid NSInternalInconsistencyException when tapping on UI elements with XCTest?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

Since upgrading to xcode 9 some of my UI tests have started throwing an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` with the message

> Activity cannot be used after its scope has completed

The problem occurs when I call `tap()` on an `XCUIElement`.  I can see that the element is a valid button, which is enabled.

Any help on fixing or working around this would be much appreciated!

The top of the stack trace for the exception is:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035ad1cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102f0ff41 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001035b2362 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x00000001029b4089 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   XCTest                              0x00000001027d4018 -[XCActivityRecord _synchronized_ensureValid] + 153
5   XCTest                              0x00000001027d3b0b -[XCActivityRecord _synchronized_addAttachment:] + 39
6   XCTest                              0x00000001027d3c98 -[XCActivityRecord addAttachment:] + 37
7   XCTest                              0x00000001027c0935 -[XCActivityRecord(UITesting) attachAutomaticScreenshot] + 265
8   XCTest                              0x00000001027f84b3 __43-[XCUIElement resolveHandleUIInterruption:]_block_invoke + 1465
9   XCTest                              0x0000000102814788 -[XCTContext _runActivityNamed:type:block:] + 185
10  XCTest                              0x00000001027f7eed -[XCUIElement resolveHandleUIInterruption:] + 139
11  XCTest                              0x000000010282b5d1 __63-[XCUIElement(XCUIElementEventSynthesis) _dispatchEvent:block:]_block_invoke + 81
12  XCTest                              0x0000000102814788 -[XCTContext _runActivityNamed:type:block:] + 185
13  XCTest                              0x000000010282b500 -[XCUIElement(XCUIElementEventSynthesis) _dispatchEvent:block:] + 315
14  XCTest                              0x000000010282d242 -[XCUIElement(XCUIElementTouchEvents) tap] +
```

Comment: Please post source code where your activity is defined.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Xcode 9, this can be caused due to a bug between `XCUITest` and the new Xcode 9 main thread checker. More details are in [this blog post](https://dzone.com/articles/main-thread-checker-and-xcuitests-with-xcode-9).

To temporarily work around this issue until Apple fixes it, disable the Main Thread checker in the Test section of your scheme:

[image]

Comment: I am still facing this issue  by deselecting Main thread checker option. Any other solution or workaround ?

Comment: @Aks Nope, this should do it. Are you sure you disabled it for the Test section and not the Run section?

Comment: Yes I unselected "Main Thread checker" option  that.. But it did not work. Now I resolved the issue with another approach.

Comment: Can you share what another approach it was?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up fixing this by retaining the element and just using the same reference to it for subsequent calls.

```
XCUIElement *searchBar = self.app.searchFields[@"Search"];
[searchBar tap];
[searchBar typeText:@"Test Guy"];
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue with my XCUItestcase. Though I unselected "Main Thread checker" in schema settings but still my test case was failing. The strange thing that it was passing on iphone 6 plus but same code was failing for 5s, 6s iphone. Here is the approach I took to resolve the issue:

```
1. Make sure you 'unselected "Main Thread checker" in test target
scheme settings
2. Take the reference of the UI element where test is crashing.
3. Before performing action. Put some sleep or have some delay.
4. Then perform the action on that element.
```

schema settings 
[image: tes schema settings]

sample :

```
   let confirmBtn = app.buttons["go"]
   sleep(2)
   confirmBtn.tap()
```